# Doing a join operation with a negative condition in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :member_tags
end
```

and

```
class MemberTag < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :member
  # has a column 'tag'
end
```

I want to perform the following join:
Member.all(:joins=>:member_tags, :conditions=>"**all members that don't have a member_tag with tag="hidden"**)

How do I do this? I guess it's more of an SQL question, than a rails one :)

Comment: While the answer is simple in SQL (left join and check for null, or write a `NOT IN` subquery), I have no idea how to express it in ActiveRecord syntax for you.

Comment: Could you please help me with this? My SQL skills are terrible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could do the trick:

```
select  `members`.*
from `members`
LEFT JOIN `member_tags`
ON `members`.id = `member_tags`.member_id
where `members`.id NOT IN (select  `members`.id
from `members`
LEFT JOIN `member_tags`
ON `members`.id = `member_tags`.member_id
where `member_tags`.tag = 'hidden'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant come up with anything better and this is an ugly method of doing it as it fires (n+1) sql queries for n members

```
Member.all.select {|member| !(member.member_tags.map(&:tag).include? "hidden")}
```

Comment: This seems to return all the members that have tag which isn't "hidden". Instead, I want all members that don't have this tag at all.

Comment: @mike..I have edited the answer though I would not recommend it.